# Efficient way to get a huge number of records sorted via Linq. Also some help regarding editing an existing DB entry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

The fist part of my question is
suppose I have a poco class

```
public class shop{
 public virtual string fruitName {get;set;}
 public virtual double numberOfFruitsLeftToConsume {get;set;}
 public virtual double numberOfFruitsLeftForStorage {get;set;}
 public virtual List<Locations> shopLocations {get;set;}
 }
```

I add new fruits in the db by creating a new object of shop and then add it via my context then save it. 
Now to retrieve the data 
will it be more efficient for me to first filter by fruit name get a List then in that collection should I run my query to sort by the number of fruits to consume , or should I just put it all into one query. Supposing that the site has more than 1000 hits/sec and a massive DB, which method will be efficient.

```
List<shop> sh = context.shopDB.Where(p => p.fruitName == "mango" &&
                                     p.fruitName == "apple").ToList();
List<shop> sh = sh.Where(f => f.numberOfFruitsLeftToConsume >= 100 &&
                         f.numberOfFruitsLeftForStorage <= 100).ToList();
```

The example has no meaning , I just wanted to show the type of query I am using.

The second part of my question is, when I initialize the class shop I do not initialize the List within it. Later on when I try to add it it does not get saved, the shop is connected to the user.

```
ApplicationUser user = await usemanager.FindByEmailAsync("email");
if(user.shops.shopLocations == null){
   user.shops.shopLocation = new List<Location>();
   uset.shops.shopLocation.Add(someLocation);
   await context.shopDB.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
 ////already tried
 //List<Location> loc = new List<Location>();
 //loc.Add(someLocation);
 //user.shops.shopLocation = loc;
 //await context.shopDB.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I tried both the methods in a try catch block and no exception is thrown.

If you need any more details or if something is not clear to you please ask.

Thank you.

If I add Location and LocationId properties to shop, and then save, I can only view the LocationId , but the Location property still remains null.
To clear any question , If I save a location Individually it saves. So I don't think I'm providing wrong data.

Comment: LINQ makes paging really simple - see [Page large result sets with LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334684.aspx).

Comment: You are speaking for **sorting**, but the sample queries do **filtering**. So what's the case?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Yes I Know that, I am using them for setting the number of pages on a different class. I cannot use it limit the number of fruit names, as that is not intended.

Comment: @IvanStoev I did not know that they are different in LINQ. Which should I use?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes filtering it is. Ill make the change in the question as well.

Comment: 1000s of calls per second in linq to a big number of data will not be very efficient, because it won't be efficient in sql, especially with sorting and paging (paging in sql works by generating the entire result set and then discarding the first rows)
Have you looked into NoSQL alternatives (SOLR, Lucene, etc.)?
Solr has a SolrNet wrapper that makes querying very simple and efficient.

Comment: @KinSlayerUY TBH, I did not know that. I just learnt this and the ms site teaching it said that it is enough so I kind of made the entire app around it. Ill look into SOLR, thank you for the tip.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

> Now to retrieve the data will it be more efficient for me to first filter by fruit name get a List then in that collection should I run my query to sort by the number of fruits to consume , or should I just put it all into one query. Supposing that the site has more than 1000 hits/sec and a massive DB, which method will be efficient.

You are the only one who can answer that question by measuring the query performance. **Only** as a **general** rule I can say that putting all into one query and let the database do the most of the job (eventually tuning it by creating appropriate indexes) is usually preferable.

What about the second part of the question (which basically is a different question), this block

```
if (user.shops.shopLocations == null)
{
   user.shops.shopLocation = new List<Location>();
   user.shops.shopLocation.Add(someLocation);
   await context.shopDB.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

looks suspicious. Your `shopLocations` member is declared as `virtual`, which means it's intended to use **lazy loading**, hence most probably will never be `null`. And even if it is `null`, you need to keep only the `new` part inside the `if` and do the rest outside, like this

```
if (user.shops.shopLocations == null)
   user.shops.shopLocation = new List<Location>();

user.shops.shopLocation.Add(someLocation);
await context.shopDB.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: I will try and measure the performance. Regarding the second part, I have tried that as well. everything works smoothly, no exceptions are thrown but the content is not saved. When I try to retrieve the data I get the null reference exception.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You explained the meaning of virtual to me finally. The second part of the question was answered by you, it turns out I did not mark the properties as virtual so ef was  not adding them efficiently. Do you know why?

Comment: Because when the properties are virtual, EF created proxy object overrides them and can track the changes that you make with code.

Answer (score 0):

**1st Question**

Because you are calling `.ToList()` at the end of your queries it will have to fetch all the rows from the db each time, so it will be much faster to do all your filtering in one LINQ `.Where()` call like this:

```
List<shop> sh = context.shopDB.Where(p => p.fruitName == "mango" && p.fruitName == "apple" && f.numberOfFruitsLeftToConsume >= 100 && f.numberOfFruitsLeftForStorage <= 100).ToList();
```

but if you don't call .ToList() at the end of first Linq query, spliting your query into two calls will be tottally fine and will yield the same performance as the previous approach like this:

```
var sh = context.shopDB.Where(p => p.fruitName == "mango" &&
                                     p.fruitName == "apple");
List<shop> shList = sh.Where(f => f.numberOfFruitsLeftToConsume >= 100 &&
                         f.numberOfFruitsLeftForStorage <= 100).ToList();
```

**2nd Question**

when you initialize the Location for the shop, you must set the shopId property and then it should work, if not the problem might be with your database relationships.

Comment: Thank you for the answer to the first question. I will try them both. Regarding the second question, where should I set the shopId property? In the Location class?

Comment: yes and it should be related to shop class, but if you are using codefirst you should set the Shop on the location class itself.

Comment: you mean this:  public   class location{ public virtual int shopId {get;set;} } or something else. Yes I am using code first, how do you mean set the shop on the location class it self, like merge them together?

Comment: Thank you so much, for your help. Sorry I cannot mark your answer as the chosen one because both the answers helped me tremendously.